# Android SQLite Async Task Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

```
 private class UploadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {  
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbs.getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(DBAdapter.KG_ID,  "q");
                        values.put(DBAdapter.KG_Used,  "False");
                        values.put(DBAdapter.KG_UsedDate,  "");
                    db.insert(DBAdapter.KG_ThisPDAIncidentIDPreAllocations, null, values);
```

In my application as soon as the code hits the line SQLiteDatabase db = dbs.getWritableDatabase(); i get an error. Can a database be accessed in a AsynTask? It is in a separate service class.

Comment: You should show both the error (from logcat) and the source for `dbs.getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: logcat isnt useful nothing shows up

Comment: Well, if you get an Exception in your app SOMETHING will show up. Have you tried running logcat from the command line with `adb logcat`? Also, you will need to include the source for the method you are calling that is failing if you want to get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work...needed this.dbs = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0):

I would try to send in the database via the parameters. That way you are not calling UI methods from a different thread. Like so.

```
UploadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<SQLiteDatabase, Void, SQLiteDatabase>
    @Override
protected SQLiteDatabase doInBackground(SQLiteDatabase... params) {
            //Do something with database and return it
            params[0].doSomeThing();
            return params[0];
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SQLiteDatabase result) {
    //Here is the database after the processing
}
```

And this is how you would construct and call the AsyncTask.

```
UploadFilesTask task = new UploadFilesTask();
task.execute(dbs.getWritableDatabase());
```

Comment: ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread$ServiceArgsData) line: 3280

Comment: 06-16 09:12:20.604: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3267)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `SQLiteDatabase db = dbs.getWritableDatabase();`outside of the AsyncTask?

If you have never run that code before I could have something to do with your database and not the AsyncTask.

I know I have used database inside of AsyncTask a couple of times now...

**Edit:** Where is dbs created/declared? I am assuming that is your SqlLiteHelper. If you declared that in your activity than it would be part of the UI thread. Try moving your declaration of dbs inside of `doInBackground(Object... arg0)`.

If you can't move the declaration of dbs inside of `doInBackgroud(Object... arg0)` (being used other places in Activity) then make sure it is declared with `final`

I would not recommend trying to pass dbs or db as a parameter to doInBackground.